# Share the same property for all instances of a structure in Swift

Tags: swift, data-structures

Let us suppose we have the following codes:

Case 1:

```swift
struct A {}

struct B {
  let a: A
  // Bench of functions that use a
  func foo1() -> B {...}
  func foo2() -> B {...}
  ...
}

let a = A()
let b = B(a: a)
b.foo1()
```

Case 2:

```swift
struct A {}

struct B {
  func foo1(a: A) -> B {...}
  func foo2(a: A) -> B {...}
  ...
}

let a = A()
let b = B()
b.foo1(a: a)
```

For the context of my real code:
I instantiate a lot of values of type `B`, and my value `a` never changes.
A lot of functions of `b` require `a` to work.

I want to know what is the best way to bring `a` without copying it.
For example, in case 1, because `a` is a property of the structure, a new value of `b` implies a copy of `a`.
In the second case, there is no copy anymore.
However, I feel pretty bad asking for `a` in each function especially when it never changes.
Thus, I want a way to store `a` without copying it.

If I had used C, I would have used a reference instead of a value for this particular value.
Do you have any suggestions or did I miss something?

Comment: This seems like a premature optimization. Use case 1 and don't worry about it unless you run into an actual issue.

Comment: Declare it as `class` and it will not be copied.

Comment: Thanks for the answers ! I had tried the `class` solution and it works well indeed.

Comment: It's enough to make A a class, which means the only thing that is copied is reference to A - not a big deal. Not a premature optimization, btw, if you deal with a lot of objects, but the right concern to have...